# Passing List into method

Tags: c#, list, methods

Simple question I think. I am trying to pass in a list that I created within my Main into a method. I am missing something but can't quite put my finger on it.

Declaration

```
List<string> emulationList = new List<string>();
```

Method Call

```
sataHeader = ParseSataHeader(sataHeader, bcuFileName, List<string> emulationList);
```

Method Implementation

```
private static string ParseSataHeader(string sataHeader, string bcuFileName, List<string> emulationList)
{
  //some code
}
```

Comment: You don't restate the type when calling a method.  Just use `sataHeader = ParseSataHeader(sataHeader, bcuFileName, emulationList);`

Comment: Voting to close since it's a simple syntax error and should have been solved by reading the compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify the type when passing arguments.

Change your second snippet to:

```
sataHeader = ParseSataHeader(sataHeader, bcuFileName, emulationList);
```

And it will work just fine.